# Inserting auto number in MS Access using C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to automatically insert numbers in my MS Access db .

Currently i have a db that looks like:

```
| id | username | password | name | email |
```

where `id` is auto incremented.

And I have this code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", tbUname.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", tbPass.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", tbName.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", tbEmail.Text.Trim());
string sql = "insert into users " +
            "values('',@userName, @password, @Name, @Email)";
```

I have tried doing this:

```
INSERT INTO users (username,password,name,email) VALUES (@userName,@password, @Name, @Email)
```

the error i get when u run this query is :

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at Default2.btsignup_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

But it doesn't work. I need it so that whenever a new user registers, a number is assigned to them.

Can some one help me out?

Comment: Do not store passwords in plain text.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: its just an example please answer the question being asked :)

Comment: `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandl` ...thats the error when i try using the second commad

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the full stack trace. The above comment is cut off

Comment: Also, please can you show the full code where you call the database. Your `ExecuteCommand` bit

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Can you repost the execption text but this time highlight the text and press the button that looks like `{ }` on the website so it keeps its formatting. Also, there may be a InnerException, the info for that would be useful too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna take a punt that `password` is a reserved field name within MS Access

try

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", tbUname.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", tbPass.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", tbName.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", tbEmail.Text.Trim());
string sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,[password],name,email) VALUES (@userName,@password, @Name, @Email)";
```

note the [ ] around `password`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan see his question - he did actually try specifying the column names: `INSERT INTO users (username,password,name,email) VALUES (@userName,@password, @Name, @Email)` - problem was the 'naked' `password` column name

Comment: Why not `[ ]` for every field?

Comment: Why not indeed. Go on, splash out, stick `[ ]` around every column :)